# Asynchronous ajax calls in a search box

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asynchronous, race-condition

I developed an asp.net solution for a customer some months ago, in which we're using AzureSearch in an input box. My approach was to send an ajax request once a second had transcurred since the last keystroke from the user. But our customer wanted it to always happen onchange of the input box, so we did that.

It has resulted in the client reporting a bug - inconsistent searches. It's because of a race condition, I logged the async calls and that's what happened. I'm thinking about adding a 0.5 sec delay to the javascript autocomplete. Or is there a better way? Like having a pool in javascript. The control we are using is jquery easy autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did not need to add a delay or a throttle. By checking its official site, I discovered two very useful properties in jquery-easy-autocomplete, which are:

- matchResponseProperty: To avoid race conditions, since the last ajax call musn't neccessarily be the last response from the backend service, it will take the last response which has a property named as specified with this attribute, which matches with the current text in the input.
- listLocation: I was trying to render a json with an anonymous list of items and a property called InputPhrase, until I came to this, so I specified the list location in the base response object and used this model for the response.

  ```
  public class SearchViewModel
  {
      public List<dynamic> Items { get; set; }
      public string InputPhrase { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Lastly, I set matchResponseProperty to "InputPhrase", and listLocation to "Items"

Comment: I can do that tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is called a "debounce". A debounce is when you have a timer start counting down when a user starts input. If they enter more input before the timer has finished, the timer is reset and starts counting down again. Only when the timer finishes does the AJAX call get made. In this case, a 200ms delay is what research has shown most people consider to still feel responsive.

However, if you really want results to pour in as the user is typing, what you need instead is called a "throttle". A throttle is similar to a debounce, except that it triggers at regular intervals, rather than waiting for the input to stop. To build one you'd still have a timer, however, you wouldn't reset it each time the user enters more input. Instead, you'd use a boolean to track whether or not new input had been entered. When the timer finishes, it checks if the boolean is true, if it is, set it to false and restart the timer counting down.

You could improve either method by keeping track of whether an AJAX call was already taking place. In both cases, if the timer runs out and the boolean tracking if a call is in progress is true, restart the timer.

Both a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) and [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) are already available in several utility libraries such as lodash. You can use them to to wrap your existing event handlers.

```
var myInputChangeHandler = function() {
  // do ajax call
};

// throttled handler will only be called every 200 ms...
var throttled = _.throttle(myInputChangeHandler, 200);
// ...no matter how many times this event fires
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('change', throttled);
```